# Laravel 4 installation on server not working

Tags: laravel-4

Hello I have installed laravel 4 on my server, the installation was done from cpanel , I get the default welcome message of Laravel on this link http://www.mysite/laravel/public

I added a controller and a view and I tried to run the url for that new controller and I get a Error 404 - Not Found

The document you are looking for may have been removed or re-named. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.

This is what I did after laravel was installed :

TestController.php

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }

}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/Test', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

views/index.php

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

am I doing something worng?

here is my folder structure :

[image]

Comment: "I get the default welcome message of Laravel on this link http://www.mysite/laravel/public" that's your problem right there. You should make Laravel's public directory the web server's root and make sure that the `AllowOverride` directive is set to something permissive enough so that Laravel's `.htaccess` can take effect.

Comment: Hi, can you be more clear with steps to do please?

Comment: I passionately hate web hosting control panels so I have no idea how to do that but a search for "laravel cpanel" should help you.

Comment: 1. Do you have SSH access? You'll need that to run artisan, for composer, migrations, etc; and 2. If you manually installed Laravel, did you include the hidden `.htaccess` file?

Comment: What was the default folder configuration before you installed laravel? Did you had a pre-existing public_html or public folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when deployed my project on a host the first time.

You should put all the content of your public folder in the pre-existing public or public_html folder and the whole app folder in the root folder of the server.

Then you change app/config/app.php to tell the new path of app to laravel, and change your .htaccess file to point the document root to the new public folder.

This worked for me, if you need additional details, ask.

Comment: I have the same problem....i need help...if you could edit your answer and write exactly which files we need to change so that laravel app works on the server like localy....